# How to refactor <link href=" " /> references in ASP.NET pages/views using ReSharper?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, resharper, href, automated-refactoring

I moved a set of ASPX pages to a different folder using [ReSharper's](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) Refactor->Move command.

[From ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_to_Folder) we have:

> **Move to Folder**
>
> This refactoring helps move a class, a file, or a selection of classes
>   or files to another project or folder in solution. When executing the
>   move, ReSharper *updates using directives* if necessary. Optionally, it
>   can *rename namespaces* according to the new location and distribute
>   classes being moved to separate files.

After moving those pages, all the links that reference CSS files got broken.

When I open an ASPX page in source view I get something like this:

[image]

I think that if it's offering a substitution it already knows where to look for the correct file.

The hint with an interrogation mark helps but I have to open each page and correct link by link.

Isn't there an automated way of correcting all the links with ReSharper 6.0? If the answer is negative, I think there should be such a feature implemented in the Move to Folder command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid, answer is negative.
Yep, prompted feature is good, not only for Move to Folder refactoring, but for general purpose (for example, cut&paste of files). We thought about it but postponed since UI is not clear (we need a way to indicate such file references, apply updates to them, and cancel, if necessary).

Comment: I thought someone from ReSharper team would answer this question. I was right! :) Thanks for letting us know that it's in the planning...